# sql query to show row data in columns

Tags: mysql, sql

Table Structure

```
Table 1 
-------------
code  |  name 
-------------
1     |  abc 
2     |  xyz


Table 2
-------------------------------
code   |  table1_code  |  data
-------------------------------
1      |    1          |  a
2      |    1          |  b
3      |    1          |  c
4      |    1          |  d
5      |    1          |  e
6      |    2          |  f
7      |    2          |  g
```

Now Expected Result:
Result

```
table1_code  | name  |   data_col1    |   data_col2   |  data_col3
------------------------------------------------------------------
1              abc       a                b              c
2              xyz       f                g              -
```

What i have tried so far

```
SELECT a.code AS table1_code, 
       a.NAME, 
       b.data_col 
FROM   table1 AS a 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 AS b 
                    ON a.code = b.table1_code
```

kindly help me to alter the query to get above output,
i want data upto 3 columns only.

Comment: always put your efforts

Comment: Yes, you can! (c) Obama

Comment: at least explain properly

Comment: now you understand what i want..

@u_mulder

Comment: not sure if homework... We are not going to do your homework for you. I Suggest reading up on the mysql documentation.

Comment: now you understand what i want.. @utility

Comment: now you understand what i want.. @Backs

Comment: now you understand what i want.. @TirthakShah

Comment: i dont need this, i can get above stuff from any where in google.
solve my logic proplem.

i write 

select a.code as table1_code, a.name,b.data_col from table1 as a left outer join table2  as b on a.code=b.table1_code

i want from you, that how to merge it with three columns 

@ThomasVdBerge

Answer (score 0):

To do this you need a way to determine what the first three items in each group should be. The way to do this is to add a row number that restarts for each new group. This would be easy in any database that supports window function, but MySQL doesn't so it gets a bit more complicated as you have to use user defined variables to do the ranking.

In the query below ranking of data is done in the derived table used as source and then a conditional aggregation is performed so that you get one row per group:

```
SELECT
  code, 
  name,
  MAX(CASE WHEN rank = 1 THEN data END) data_col1,
  MAX(CASE WHEN rank = 2 THEN data END) data_col2,
  MAX(CASE WHEN rank = 3 THEN data END) data_col3
FROM (
  SELECT
    a.code, 
    a.name,
    b.data,
    ( 
      CASE a.name 
        WHEN @grp THEN @row := @row + 1 
        ELSE @row := 1 AND @grp := a.name
      END
    ) + 1 AS rank
  FROM table1 AS a 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 AS b ON a.code = b.table1_code
  , (SELECT @row := 0, @grp := '') r
  ORDER BY a.code, a.name asc
) src
GROUP BY code, name;
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1afaf/13)